# PostGIS geometry intersection test results different for Point and Linestring

Tags: postgis, intersection, linestring

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how do I avoid the problem? I'll attempt to clarify what I'm doing as things go along.

The geom column is a multipolygon column, all values are SRID=4326.

```
archive=> select st_intersects( GeomFromewkt('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-16.899216666666668 12.610816666666667,-16.899216666666668 12.610816666666667)') 
, z.geom) as intersects
from zone z
where z.zone_id=2;
 intersects 
------------
 f
(1 row)

archive=> select   st_intersects( GeomFromewkt('SRID=4326;POINT(-16.899216666666668 12.610816666666667)') 
, z.geom) as intersects
from zone z
where z.zone_id=2;
 intersects 
------------
 t
(1 row)
```

This is the text representation of the geom:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((-18.7273147400488 12.8862644964914,-18.7334078119781 12.3609663554343,-16.5597662148828 12.3796303212717,-16.6302631480867 13.1209501528692,-18.7273147400488 12.8862644964914)))
```

How can the linestring not intersect with the geometry, yet a single point does? Is this some sort of rounding error, or a problem because the linestring has a length of zero? If the length is the problem, how do I avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you post the WKT of the multipolygon?

Comment: Sure - I just used the `st_astext` function - I'm not sure why it didn't say SRID=4326; at the front, but it is of the same type.

Comment: To get the SRID, use [`ST_AsEWKT`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html) (*extended* well-known text)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, it looks like that is the behaviour from JTS and GEOS. The problem is that your LINESTRING is invalid. If you have PostGIS 2.0, you can use [ST_MakeValid(geometry)](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html) to fix the LINESTRING to a POINT.

This query verifies your bug, and uses ST_MakeValid as a workaround.

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'POLYGON((150 280, 99 215, 190 210, 150 280))'::geometry AS poly,
                     'POINT(170 240)'::geometry AS pt)

SELECT ST_Intersects(poly, pt) AS intersects_poly_pt,
       ST_Intersects(poly, ST_MakeLine(pt, pt)) AS intersects_poly_line,
       ST_IsValid(ST_MakeLine(pt, pt)) AS isvalid_line,
       ST_AsText(ST_MakeValid(ST_MakeLine(pt, pt))) AS valid_geom,
       ST_Intersects(poly, ST_MakeValid(ST_MakeLine(pt, pt))) AS intersects_poly_valid_geom
FROM data;
```

with results (using psql's `\x` option):

```
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point 170 240
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+---------------
intersects_poly_pt         | t
intersects_poly_line       | f
isvalid_line               | f
valid_geom                 | POINT(170 240)
intersects_poly_valid_geom | t
```

---

If you are using a previous version of PostGIS (pre 2.0), then you can cast from an invalid LINESTRING to a box2d, then back to a GEOMETRY. For a two-vertex LINESTRING with same coordinates, this turns into a POINT. Here is the PostGIS 1.5 version of the above:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'POLYGON((150 280, 99 215, 190 210, 150 280))'::geometry AS poly,
                     'LINESTRING(170 240, 170 240)'::geometry AS line)

SELECT ST_Intersects(poly, line) AS intersects_bad_line,
       ST_IsValid(line) AS isvalid_line,
       ST_AsText(CASE WHEN NOT ST_IsValid(line) THEN line::box2d::geometry
                      ELSE line END) as valid_geom,
       ST_Intersects(poly, CASE WHEN NOT ST_IsValid(line) THEN line::box2d::geometry
                                ELSE line END) AS intersects_poly_valid_geom
FROM data;
```

with results:

```
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point 170 240
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point 170 240
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point 170 240
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+---------------
intersects_bad_line        | f
isvalid_line               | f
valid_geom                 | POINT(170 240)
intersects_poly_valid_geom | t
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're using 1.5 - is there an alternative method?

Comment: For 1.5, you can try casting from `geometry::box2d::geometry`, as updated above.